# Migrating from maven to Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-3

I am planning to migrate from maven to gradle. Before starting i have a query which i want all of your view. My Project pom has a reference to an external project as the parent reference which is using maven and we dont have control to change that as it is managed by others.
like below.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.package.apiBuider</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</parent>
```

So just wanted to check is it possible to migrate my project to gradle while leaving the parent reference which my project is using, to maven.

-Sam

Comment: According to my knowledge it will not work. Please, have a look here as well: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-gradle-reuse-maven-parent-pom/9119/3

Answer (score 1):

As of Gradle 4.6 there is core support for [BOM Import](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#bom-import). So if you only need the `<dependencyManagement>` section from the parent pom you can use this

See https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/#bills_of_materials_boms

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [gradle maven transform](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform) plugin to transform a pom.xml into a gradle file which is you then `apply` in your gradle project.

Comment: So how do you use it? An example?